# How Can you factor $1/2$ out of integral of $\cos2x$?

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry

$$ \int \cos 2x\,dx $$

simplifies to $$ \frac{1}{2} \int \cos u \, du$$ where $u = 2x$

My Question is where does the $1/2$ that is factored out come from?

It would make more sense for a factor of $1/2$ to be extracted if the integral was:
$$ \int \frac{\cos x} 2 \, dx$$

Comment: Well, do you understand how $dx$ and $du$ are related? And do you know that $\frac 1 2 \int f(x) \, dx = \int \frac{f(x)}{2} \, dx$?

Comment: Ask yourself: using that $u=2x$, what is $du$ (expressed in terms of $x$)? And next, what is $dx$ (expressed in terms of $u$)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you do a $u$-substitution, you have to substitute for every $x$ in the integral, including the $dx$. Starting from $u=2x$, you can differentiate both sides and get $\frac{du}{dx}=2$. We rewrite this as $\frac12 du=dx$.

Thus, when you substitute in the integral, you replace the $2x$ with a simple $u$, and you replace the $dx$ with $\frac12 du$. We write the $\frac12$ out in front of the integral, and then we proceed with our simpler integral in terms of $u$.

Comment: Thank you. Your answer was well explained. 'du' and 'dx' and the 'd-variable' part of integrals have been a problem for me ever since I started calculus, especially when discerning whether they are part of the integration and factorable or just there to address a certain variable.

Answer (score 1):

$$I=\int \cos 2x dx$$

Let $2x=u\rightarrow du=2dx$

Substituting: $$I=\int\cos u\left(\dfrac{du}2\right)=\int\dfrac{\cos u}2 du=\dfrac 12\int \cos u du$$

Comment: Please [edit] your post to include MathJax - image only answers are generally discouraged because they are hard to read and unsearchable. If you aren't sure how to format your post, [read this](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 0):

To be more scrutinized, you can see it is because of $du = 2\,dx$.